# unziping files in linux folder

Tags: linux, bash, unzip

in `Python` I have the following command executed `unzip '{dir}ATTOM_RECORDER/*.zip' -d {dir}ATTOM_RECORDER/` as a bash command.  The python call works perfectly.  my question is about the unzip command itself.

for some reason when unzip is called to expand any relevent zip files in the folder specified, not all the files WITHIN the zip is extracted.  There's usually a rpt and a txt file.  However, sometimes the txt file is not coming out and I do not have an error command.

How can I ensure the txt file is guaranteed to be extracted before moving on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While you want to unzip your specific zip file. There are many option to decompress any file from zip files. Easiest way is **the ‘-l’ option with unzip command is used to list the contents of a zip file** after extracting it.

Syntax: **unzip -l [file_name.zip]**